# How can I take a list of values, perform multiple "cleaning" operations on them and place them elsewhere in the workbook?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, user-defined-functions, udf

I just spent most of the day trying to figure out how to do this, and the most I've gotten is one or two of the operations I wanted done, and then I can't get the rest to work.

I will preface by saying that I currently have an "Intermediate" worksheet for multi-step processes, so having to do what I want that way is perfectly acceptable.

Now for that actual problem:

- I have a very large list (approaching 2000 lines) of raw data. Each cell in this list can contain either nothing (blank), 0, or either a 6 digit number (243300, 143356, etc.) or multiple 6 digit numbers in the same cell, separated by a space.

What I want to do is:

1. Remove all blank cells
2. Separate, if applicable, cells that contain more than one value
3. Remove the duplicate values
4. Sort the remaining values alpha-numerically
5. Place the resulting list in the "Main" worksheet, for a clean presentation to the users.

The solution cannot modify the values in the raw list (that's why I have the "Intermediate" worksheet)
It also needs to be done automatically, so no Macros.

---

What I currently have is either:

```
    =IFERROR(INDEX(Raw!$G$2:$G$5000, MATCH(0, COUNTIF(Intermediate!$F$2:$F2, Raw!$G$2:$G$5000), 0)),"")
```

which gives me a list without blanks, no duplicates, but not sorted, and without the multi-value cells split;
or

```
    Public Function Blah(ParamArray args()) As String
'Declarations
Dim uniqueParts As Collection
Dim area As Range
Dim arg, arr, ele, part
Dim i As Long

'Initialisations
Set uniqueParts = New Collection

'Enumerate through the arguments passed to this function
For Each arg In args
    If TypeOf arg Is Range Then 'range so we need to enumerate its .Areas
        For Each area In arg.Areas
        arr = area.Value 'for large ranges it is greatly quicker to load the data at once rather than enumerating each cell in turn
            For Each ele In arr 'enumerate the array
                 addParts CStr(ele), uniqueParts 'Call our sub to parse the data
            Next ele
        Next area
    ElseIf VarType(arg) > vbArray Then 'an array has been passed in
        For Each ele In arg 'enumerate the array
            addParts CStr(ele), uniqueParts 'Call our sub to parse the data
        Next ele
    Else 'assume can be validly converted to a string. If it cannot then it will fail fast (as intended)
        addParts CStr(arg), uniqueParts 'Call our sub to parse the data
    End If
Next arg

'process our results
If uniqueParts.Count > 0 Then
    ReDim arr(0 To uniqueParts.Count - 1)
    For i = 1 To uniqueParts.Count
        arr(i - 1) = uniqueParts(i)
    Next i
    'we now have an array of the unique parts, which we glue together using the Join function, and then return it
    Blah = Join(arr, ",")
End If

End Function
'Sub to parse the data. In this case the sub splits the string and adds the split elements to a collection, ignoring duplicates
Private Sub addParts(partsString As String, ByRef outputC As Collection)
'ByRef is unecessary but I use it to document that outputC must be instantiated
    Dim part
    For Each part In Split(partsString, ",")
        On Error Resume Next 'existing same key will raise an error, so we skip it and just carry on
        outputC.Add part, part
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next part
End Sub
```

which I was given a few years ago for a different need. This UDF splits multi-value cells, gets rid of blanks and duplicates, but concatenates the result afterwards.

I'm unfortunately a noob when it comes to UDF and VBA, so I can't even figure out how to change that UDF so it exports to a series of rows instead of merging the results. (I know it's the "Join" part at the end, but I don't know what to replace it with)

I'm aware that this is a tall order, but any help or nudges in the right direction are greatly welcome.

Feel free to ask if I forgot to include helpful information.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I wouldn't know how to achieve all of that in one single step without using a macro (which is according to your question not an option). Unless @Jeeped has a clue I am pretty sure you are out of luck.

Comment: Have to agree, this looks to be more than a "tall order" if you can't use VBA. Funny thing is that this would be a trivial tasks with VBA and could be fully "automatic" if you trapped the events that you wanted to trigger the calculation.

Comment: "It also needs to be done automatically, so no Macros" this statement is nonsense.  Like saying "I need to wear pants, so I cannot wear pants."  Macros are how Excel is automated.  You cannot automate Excel without Macros.

Comment: Of note: Step 1 cannot be accomplished with a UDF, except perhaps through some ill-advised hack.  For this you will need a macro.

Comment: @n8: UDFs are in VBA too, no? Do you consider UDFs as Macros too? To me, Macros are functions or a series of actions that you need to "press start to run".
What I'm looking for is a (or multiple) UDFs that I can just enter in cells, as custom formulas, that will eventually get me the result I seek, dynamically, without having to manually run them each time.

Also, for step one, it's already being done with my first example (the one that starts with =IFERROR( ) so I hardly see it as impossible without a "hack".

Comment: @Ralph Doesn't have to be in one single step. Like I said, I use an "Intermediate" worksheet for any multi-step process, so the user will only see the end-result.

Comment: @Ambie I might have misunderstood terms then. I can use VBA for this (as shown with my second sample, which is a UDF). I just don't want something that requires user-input to run, which was my understanding of what a macro is.

Comment: UDFs return a single value, it populates a single cell.  All macros are VBA, but not all VBA are macros.  I was speaking purely in terms of your language, a UDF cannot "Remove all blank cells", but it can disregard them.

Comment: What you are trying to do is set up something that will run very slowly, be very hard to understand, and be very hard to validate.  Can I ask why you are opposed to requiring a user-trigger?

Comment: @n8 Lets just say I have limited trust in my users' ability to not screw up.

Although I guess I won't have much choice, based on the feedback I got here. Just gotta hope for the best.

Comment: There are a lot of options.  For example, you can schedule a job to run the macro if the data source is dumped on a schedule, so users just get the end product.  There are a lot of ways to constrain user input.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution in vba :)

```
Sub PerformTask()
    Dim oSel As Range
    Dim oWS As Worksheet
    Dim iCol As Integer
    Dim iMax As Integer

    iMax = 10

    'Copy original sheet
    Set oWS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    oWS.Copy after:=oWS

    ' get the new worksheet
    Set oWS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(oWS.Index + 1)

    'sort column to remove blanks
    SortColumn oWS, 1

    Set oSel = oWS.Columns(1)
    oSel.TextToColumns DataType:=xlDelimited, Space:=True 'parse data

    ' sort columns assuming not more than 10 if more change iMax
    For iCol = 2 To iMax
        SortColumn oWS, iCol 'Sort column to remove blanks
    Next

    'copy data to column 1
    For iCol = 2 To iMax
        Set oSel = oWS.Cells(1, iCol)

        ' if more than one row select all
        If oSel.Offset(1, 0).Value <> "" Then
            Set oSel = Range(oSel, oSel.End(xlDown))
        End If

        oSel.Cut

        ' Move to the last free cell on column 1
        oWS.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
        oWS.Paste
    Next

    SortColumn oWS, 1 'Sort

End Sub

Sub SortColumn(poWS As Worksheet, piCol As Integer)
    Dim oSel As Range

    Set oSel = poWS.Columns(piCol)
    With poWS.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add oSel
        .SetRange oSel
        .Apply
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Can you tell me what the syntax is for it though?

I tried to just add the range of values in the Raw worksheet (one column, 4000 lines) and it gives me a #NAME error.

(Also, I had to rename the function, since excel tells me "PerformTask" is not a valid name (possibly because it conflicts with a built-in name)

Comment: #NAME error means that the function doesn't exist.  This is a macro, so you cannot call it as a UDF.  You just run it.

Comment: as per @n8 comment,  the task is not suitable for UDF.  Macro/vba is more suitable for the purpose.

Comment: Oh okay, I'm gonna have to look up how to set up/use macros then.

Thanks for the code :D